# GridView doesn't show any elements

Tags: java, android, gridview, custom-adapter

My GridView is supposed to show elements passed to CustomAdapter but there are no entries at all. The app fetches data from database and there everything works fine. It gets all elements in the array. The code that sends a request to recieve data is in a fragment.
That is the code to fetch data:

```
private class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String stringURL = "xyz_php_file";
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            url = new URL(stringURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        String username, name, description;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
        int i;

        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(result);
            location = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for(i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("username", object.getString("username"));
                map.put("name", object.getString("name"));
                map.put("description", object.getString("description"));
                location.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(location != null){
            for(i = 0; i < location.size(); i++){
                username = location.get(i).get("username").toString();
                name = location.get(i).get("name").toString();
                description = location.get(i).get("description").toString();

                products.add(new Product(username, name, description));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some code from fragment:

```
private GridView mainGridView;
private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

And now that is the way I initialized GridView and CustomAdapter in the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    new RetrieveData().execute();

    TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
    if(products != null){
        data.setText("Data loaded successfully");
    }else{
        data.setText("Error while downloading");
    }

    mainGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealsgridview);
    CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(view.getContext(), products);
    mainGridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

My CustomAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Product> productsList;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> sentProduct){
    this.context = context;
    this.productsList = sentProduct;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_grid_layout, parent, false);

    Product product = productsList.get(position);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

    name.setText(product.getName());

    description.setText(product.getDescription());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

And finally my Product Class:

```
public class Product {

private String username;
private String name;
private String description;

public Product(String username, String name, String description) {
    this.username = username;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

}

When I launch application and switch to home fragment it shows "Data loaded successfully", so I believe the app gets all data from database and ArrayList isn't emnpty but there is no elements shown in GridView. Where might be a problem? 
I will appreciate your answers! I've read some tutorials, watched videos but my code still doesn't want to work.

Comment: Where and when call RetrieveData  AsyncTask?

Comment: You need to call notifyDataSetChanged(); after fetching data .

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi app executes RetrieveData in onCreateView, so ArrayList should be populated before initializing GridView and CustomAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this lines of code right after closing for loop

```
    mainGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealsgridview);
    CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(view.getContext(), products);
    mainGridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I mean after this for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < location.size(); i++){
                username = location.get(i).get("username").toString();
                name = location.get(i).get("name").toString();
                description = location.get(i).get("description").toString();

                products.add(new Product(username, name, description));
            }
```

Comment: you are calling this lines after executing the asynctask

Comment: @Sunsil P I cannot call mainGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealsgridview); in RetrieveData method because it doesnt have view parameter.

Comment: hey make view as global variable, you got what I m saying

Comment: If you help, you deserve it.

Comment: Let's say that I would like to fetch data in MainActivity not in fragment because I think that is more efficient and data doesn't have to load every time we switch between different fragments like it is now, how I can solve this problem, because then I wouldnt be able to add mainGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealsgridview);
    CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(view.getContext(), products);
    mainGridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); to RetreiveData method. I know I should use parcelable but then anyway I should find different solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165821/discussion-between-sunil-p-and-d-b).

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread.

Try this one,

**onCreateView**

```
 TextView data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
    if(products != null){
        data.setText("Data loaded successfully");
    }else{
        data.setText("Error while downloading");
    }

    mainGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealsgridview);
    CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(view.getContext(), products);
    mainGridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
new RetrieveData().execute();
```

And in **onPostExecute**,

```
arrayAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I needed to implement mainGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mealsgridview);
    CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(view.getContext(), products);
    mainGridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); in my RetrieveData. The problem is sorted out now, many thanks.